# HTACCESS: HTTP to HTTPS w/ required trailing slash, www & exception for dir & page

Tags: .htaccess

I have htaccess code that requires a trailing slash and www. When I try to add various lines of code to redirect http to https it breaks my site and gives an error that there are too many redirects.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

################ Require ending trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I've tried adding this  code and changing the url above to https

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com
# ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page1/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page2/
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

In addition to redirecting http to https I'd like to not redirect for a particular directory and page /dir/   &    /dir2/blabla.html

I guess it might be easier to scrap what I have than try to add something in....

New question...

How do I redirect http to https except for a directory and a .html file. While requiring a trailing slash and www?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFlare does not allow https redirects to work from htaccess. It causes a redirection loop. https redirect rule must be set in cloudflare.